# automatically pushing sourceforge commits to github

Tags: git, github, mirror, sourceforge

I would like my sourceforge git repository be mirrored automatically on github.

Whenever I push (or anybody else with write access) something to sourceforge, the commit should "appear" on github.

There are two restrictions:

- the pushing user should not need to do any configuration on their side (e.g. adding two remotes and pushing to both is *not* a solution)
- i would like to go *without* any intermedia service I have to setup myself (e.g. a server that listens for webhook events from sf, then does a checkout of the updated repo, and pushes the changeset to github)

I have searched [long and far](https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/git-mirroring-from-sourceforge-to-github/) but haven't found anything satisfying yet...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sourceforge webhooks](https://sourceforge.net/blog/how-to-use-webhooks-for-git-mercurial-and-svn-repositories/) are generally the right way to put in place some mirroring feature.

But since you don't won't webhook, nor do you want a client-side config, then you would still need to put in place *somewhere* a "pulling service" that would, on regular interval, fetch from the sourceforge repo and, if any new commit is detected, `git push --mirror` to github.

---

> the question was mainly whether sf can talk directly to github to trigger a "pull" on github.

No, Sf does not talk directly to GitHub.

Comment: i'm not against webhooks - e.g. if i can tell sf to directly talk to github to trigger a sync via a webhook, that's cool; i would like to avoid setting up my own server though, solely to answer the sf.webhook.

Comment: @umläute webhook or not, you still need some kind of process (either to listen to the webhook payload, or to fetch regularly from the sf repo)

Comment: i guess the question was mainly whether sf can talk directly to github to trigger a "pull"  **on github**.

Comment: @umläute Then the answer would be "no". I have edited the answer accordingly.